# Soft delete or Hard Delete

Tags: magento2, database, soft-delete, hard-delete

I have very very simple general question. Is **Magento** using **soft delete** or **hard delete** for **table records**? If its using hard delete means, what is the reason? why we are not following soft delete?

Answer (score 0):

Magento uses **hard delete**.

I don't know  why - but one might guess that it is because the number of tables used to save a product (i.e. many tables, few fields) for it's EAV system would mean it is far to complicated.

Another guess would be that there are many ways to stop a product showing on the store that they could be considered a soft delete.